# Apache 2.2 SSLCADNRequestFile Option

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

I'm configuring my Apache server on RHEL5 with httpd 2.2.3. Users authenticate using a smartcard with several certificates, but we want to limit the choices to browser displays to a specific one. We've figured out how to do this by using SSLCADNRequestFile set to a .pem containing the intermediate chain of that specific type of certificate.

The problem is that we have multiple name-based virtualhosts defined on a single IP. It appears the Apache sends the response to the browser on which certificates it accepts based on the first vhost on that IP, even if the servername does not match. So unless I define SSLCADNRequestFile in the first vhost or at the server level, I cannot limit the certificate choices. Additionally, every other vhost is impacted by this setting.

Is there a way to use a name-based vhost and define the SSLCADNRequestFile per vhost? My configuration is a little different, so there could be other issues at play, below is roughly my config.

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/private.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/root-certs.pem
    SSLCADNRequestFile conf.d/certs-email-only.pem
    SSLVerifyClient none
    SSLVerifyDepth 2
    SSLOptions +ExportCertData

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    DirectoryIndex main.html

    ProxyPass /api/login ajp://localhost:8009/backend/login
    ProxyPassReverse /api/login ajp://localhost:8009/backend/login

    Alias /login /var/www/login
    <Directory /var/www/login>
        DirectoryIndex login.html
    </Directory>

    ProxyPass /logout ajp://localhost:8009/backend/logout
    ProxyPassReverse /logout ajp://localhost:8009/backend/logout

    <Location /api>
         SSLVerifyClient require
         ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/backend
         ProxyPassReverse ajp://localhost:8009/backend
         ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /backend /api
         ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost www.mysite.com
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
     # VirtualHost impacted by the SSLCADNRequestFile in the above vhost
</VirtualHost>
```